# Would forward error correction help?

Tags: error-correction, networking

I am working with a 433 Mhz transmitter for an arduino project. I found a Manchester encoding library on github(https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino-libs-manchester). It has checksums built in but the data rate for successfully received packets is very low because a lot of packets have errors. If I implemented a forward error correction scheme would that help the overall data rate. More specifically what is the math to determine if the added overhead is worth it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have the math to help you.  Just some experience with systems that used forward error correction and some that don't.  Forward error correction can help immensly.  I used one system that could successfully receive data packets well over 90% of the time in conditions where your ears would be hard pressed to tell if there were even a signal present (signal to noise ratio at or below one.)  That compared to other systems where even with a guaranteed signal to noise ratio of 20dB you had to transmit each packet twice to be sure it got through.

Comment: Excellent question which involves Shannon's Law , Signal BW, BER, group delay distortion in the channel vs bit rate and the FEC correction power vs overhead  e.g. 1 bit Hamming or 11 bit burst error.   the slope of BER vs SNR is the key to any channel vs Bit rate*Jitter or phase error between clock and data recoveryIn a HDD powerful FEC can improve hard Error rate by several orders of magnitude but depends on Noise properties if Gaussian or coherent from ISI. My guess your problem is coherent ISI and thus FEC improvement is much smaller **Can you be more specific with that example?**

Comment: e.g. schematic and waveforms with baud rate and BER vs SNR or jitter then I can give some solutions or math. I dont want to overwhelm the question with too much complexity

Comment: There are explicit formulae to determine BER vs Friss Loss and Signal BW/Channel BW vs modulation type (FM vs ASK) with friis loss and thus resulting Rx Noise spectra from ISI or Gaussian or fading loss . but typ el cheapo 433MHz Tx Rx is Frequency Range: 433.92MHz
 Modulate Mode: ASK
 Circuit Shape: SAW
 Date Rate: 8Kbps
 Supply Voltage: 1.5~12V
 Output Power : 14dBm... so in order to get 1Mbps first the BW must exceed match data spectrum then Shannon and Friis Laws define BER for a defined Rx signal threshold

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, from the bit between your happy teeth, it looks like we've inadvertently stumbled upon one of your favourite subjects :-)

Comment: One of hundreds of my past happy experiences in the 70's and 80's and not just  telemetry design

Comment: Bit rate can be doubled using NRZi with stable f and small BW PLL to recover clock then doubled again with QPSK or quadrature modulation 64 level  using Trellis coding and FEC go from 1200 baud to 64kBd in 4kHz channel  or modify Tx and Rx Saw Filter BW and get 1Mbps with 25KHz BW using PLL's or simply spew 4MHz BW with BiPhase at 1Mbps with self clocking. Thousands of papers on this subject alone to maximize SNR and 1/BER

Comment: That 64-QAM needs good SNR. And either good link phasenoise or excellent phase tracking in the DSP-demod.